# How do I set up a preload file for node?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to preload some file before each time I run `node` (interactively), just like `.vimrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.?

I use `node` mainly interactively, and I use the module `CSV` a lot, is there a way to avoid typing `require('./csv')` every time I start `node`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an initialization file (for example **~/.noderc**):

```
var csv = require('csv');

// put a blank line at the end of the file
```

Now add this line to your shell config (**.bashrc** / **.zshrc** / whatever shell you use):

```
alias nodei="cat ~/.noderc - | node -i"
```

Voilà!

Comment: What does the dash `-` do?

Comment: The `-` tells cat to use the input from `stdin`, if any is present. The `stdin` data is treated like just another file, so `cat` will output the contents of `~/.noderc` plus whatever gets piped into it. In this particular case, it gies you the option to pipe another file into the `nodei` command to run extra preload code, e.g. `cat anotherFile.js | nodei`.

Answer (score 4):

@Ilan Frumer provided one way to do it. I think I'll give another choice here: build a `REPL` of your own.

From [their documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html). You can find a way to write a repl of your own. You can add whatever scripts before and after the interations of it, and even use some advance API's.

For example, I created a file called `.noderc.js` under `~` as follows

```
repl = require('repl');

myFunc = function(){
    console.log("Hello, there!");
};

repl.start("> ");
```

And you can go ahead and `alias nodei="node ~/.noderc.js"`,

```
$ nodei
> myFunc()
Hello, there!
undefined
```