# Initialize Node.js with script and then provide a console

Tags: node.js, bash

For testing purposes, I would like to make it possible to spawn a Node.js console that reads commands from `STDIN` but *before* runs a bootstrap script to initialize several variables in the local scope.

Does `node` provide a specific option for this?

I tried to do the trick with the following bash script, but unfortunately, it outputs nothing:

```
{ cat bootstrap.js; cat; } | node
```

Comment: What's the format of `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: A simple script that sets local variables such as `var M = require('module'); var m = M('some value');`. The goal is to obtain a JS console where variables are already set for convenience so that they do not have to be reinitialized manually every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the script quoted in the question is only missing the `node` option `-i` that causes node to

> always enter the REPL even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal

As a consequence, this does the trick:

```
cat bootstrap.js - | node -i
```

The behavior is still not optimal though as `STDIN` is printed twice.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23037234/449012 for another solution that behaves just like the default console.